# Minecraft 1.15.2 freezes PC on start up

Tags: java, minecraft

When I load up Minecraft 1.15.2, it opens up a black window. Seconds later, everything freezes apart from my mouse input. A moment later, then Minecraft’s menu music starts playing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu? Is this a new install of Ubuntu? Is this a new install of Minecraft? If so, link to the instructions that you followed to install Minecraft.

Comment: @user535733 it is Ubuntu 19.10, a new install of Optifine, and I used the .deb file off minecraft.net.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I had to disable the ‘Force Quit and Wait’ thing. Now it opens properly.
(The extension is at extensions.gnome.org)